# Flutter: Text Alignment differs from IOS to Android

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I came across a problem with my fonts. Somehow the SizedBox I used which contains some Text doesn't align properly on the left in the Android Emulator like it does on the IOS simulator. It looks like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBdxz.png) In addition, the fontsizes don't match either.

Any Ideas how to fix this?

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: CustomScrollView(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          expandedHeight: 80,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            title: FittedBox(
              child: SizedBox(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: const Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                    child: Text("Browse through the individual categories.", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 32, color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w900)),
                  ),
                ),
              )
            )
          ),
        ),
        buildCategories(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Have you managed to find a fix? I am also facing a similar issue and I think this is an issue with FlexibleSpaceBar where in Android there is space on the left side but not in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I added the `centerTitle: true` property to the `FlexibleSpaceBar` and now it looks consistent on both Android and iOS.

Was facing the same issue and upon looking at the `FlexibleSpaceBar` code, this is because of the default `titlePadding` being applied based on the `centerTitle` which is then based on the TargetPlatform (in this case whether iOS or Android) if you did not specify any `centerTitle` value. Below is the `FlexibleSpaceBar` code which does the application of `titlePadding` based on platform:

```
bool _getEffectiveCenterTitle(ThemeData theme) {
    if (widget.centerTitle != null) return widget.centerTitle!;
    assert(theme.platform != null);
    switch (theme.platform) {
      case TargetPlatform.android:
      case TargetPlatform.fuchsia:
      case TargetPlatform.linux:
      case TargetPlatform.windows:
        return false;
      case TargetPlatform.iOS:
      case TargetPlatform.macOS:
        return true;
    }
  }


final bool effectiveCenterTitle = _getEffectiveCenterTitle(theme);
final EdgeInsetsGeometry padding = widget.titlePadding ??
     EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(
        start: effectiveCenterTitle ? 0.0 : 72.0,
        bottom: 16.0,
     );
```

And so, the answer is it's either you set a `titlePadding` or set `centerTitle` to `true`.